# Remove Duplicates in a Column and enter Sum in another Column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove duplicates based on the text in Column I and sum the values in Column C, the data in the other columns doesn't matter.

I do not want a pivot table and I am aware they are the preferred option for this type of thing.

An example of what I'd like to achieve:

[image: For this data]

[image: To end up like this]

I found VBA code and tried to modify it. It doesn't delete all the lines.

```
Sub Sum_and_Dedupe()
With Worksheets("data")
    'deal with the block of data radiating out from A1
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        'step off the header and make one column wider
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count + 1).Offset(1, 0)
            .Columns(.Columns.Count).Formula = "=sumifs(c:c, i:i, i2)"
            .Columns(3) = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Value
            .Columns(.Columns.Count).Delete
        End With

        'remove duplicates
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(9), Header:=xlYes
    End With
    .UsedRange
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: And what about one simple sumif formula in a helper column? And remove duplicates with inbuild function right after?

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to change your current sheet name to *data*, or change the first two lines of this code to fit your needs. `sh` = the data sheet that you showed us. `osh` = an output sheet that this code will generate. Note also if column C or I move you can update the positions easily by changing `colBooked` and `colEstimate`. If you have more than a thousand unique *estimate* entries then make the array number larger than 999.

```
Sub summariseEstimates()
    Dim sh As String: sh = "data"
    Dim osh As String: osh = "summary"
    Dim colBooked As Integer: colBooked = 3
    Dim colEstimate As Integer: colEstimate = 9
    Dim myArray(999) As String
    Dim shCheck As Worksheet
    Dim output As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim a As Integer: a = 0
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim r As Long 'row anchor
    Dim i As Integer 'sheets

    'Build summary array:
    With Worksheets(sh)
        lastRow = .Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        For r = 2 To lastRow
            If r = 2 Then 'first entry
                myArray(a) = .Cells(r, colEstimate) & "," & .Cells(r, colBooked)
            Else
                For b = 0 To a
                    If VBA.LCase(VBA.Replace(.Cells(r, colEstimate), " ", "")) = VBA.LCase(VBA.Replace(VBA.Split(myArray(b), ",")(0), " ", "")) Then 'match
                        myArray(b) = VBA.Split(myArray(b), ",")(0) & "," & VBA.Split(myArray(b), ",")(1) + .Cells(r, colBooked)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next b
                If b = a + 1 Then 'completed loop = no match, create new array item:
                    a = a + 1
                    myArray(a) = .Cells(r, colEstimate) & "," & .Cells(r, colBooked)
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    End With

    'Create summary sheet:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set shCheck = Worksheets(osh)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set output = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(sh))
        output.Name = osh
        Err.Clear
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        If MsgBox("*" & osh & "* sheet already exists. Proceed to delete and recreate?", vbOKCancel, "Summary") = vbCancel Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Worksheets(osh).Delete
            Set output = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(sh))
            output.Name = osh
        End If
    End If

    'Output to summary sheet:
    With Worksheets(osh)
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "ESTIMATE"
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = "BOOKED THIS WEEK"
        For b = 0 To a
            .Cells(b + 2, 1).Value = VBA.Split(myArray(b), ",")(0)
            .Cells(b + 2, 2).Value = VBA.Split(myArray(b), ",")(1)
        Next b
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your answer. Your code doesnt seem to work for me either. It seems to copy the data from Column C and I and puts it all in the summary sheet, it doesnt sum or remove the duplicates.

Comment: Are there any slight variations in how the duplicate "estimate" data appears? for example, do some have spaces at the end, or a mixture of upper/lowercase?

Comment: Thats interesting, I checked the data and some of the estimate data contains spaces, thank you very much for pointing that out!

Comment: OK, no need to change your data... I've edited the code so it's case insensitive, and it ignores spaces.

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much for your time for doing this, it works great! I may need to try and modify it so it will do everything on the same sheet but if I cant, a least I have got this! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This should be an answer to your question.
However, code might require adaptation if the range in which you look becomes very long.

Option Explicit

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, a As Double, i As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Variant, Estimate As Variant

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set Rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 9), ws.Cells(LastRow, 9))


    For Each Cell In Rng
        i = 0
        a = 0
        For Each Estimate In Rng
            If Estimate.Value = Cell.Value Then
                i = i + 1   'Count nr of intances
                a = a + ws.Cells(Estimate.Row, 3).Value 'sum booking value
                If i > 1 Then
                    ws.Rows(Estimate.Row).Delete
                    i = 1
                    LastRow = LastRow - 1
                End If
            End If
        Next Estimate
        ws.Cells(Cell.Row, 3).Value = a 'Enter sum in booked this week
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I have tried your code and it doesnt seem to work for me, it seems to round the numbers up to the nearest whole number in Column C and that's it, doesnt delete duplicates either

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. The script runs and completes without any errors, but nothing happens, doesnt sum the data, and doesnt remove duplicates, just shows a lot of random data in the debug screen

Comment: It turns out I had some blank spaces after each estimate which is why it didnt work. It works and deletes duplicates, only problem is it sumed 2 of 3 records instead of all 3

Comment: Which value wasn't summer? Line was not deleted either I guess? Was it thé last row? Van you upvote thé answer if it was helpful or accept?

Comment: Lines deleted, only left with 1 line as I wanted, the last row that deleted did not add

Comment: Before: https://imgur.com/a/CEKIDsW and After: https://imgur.com/a/wCfThkD

Comment: Both values in col I, first 2 Rows are not equal, only explanation. Check again for spaces and other differences